# ORA-12170 error occurred

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, toad, ora-12170

I am trying to connect oracle 10g db through TOAD from another machine. But failed, got error as

> ORA-12170 connection timeout occurred.

Please help me.

Comment: Well, you haven't said how you're connecting, what settings you're using, what the DB/listener config is. Possibly either using the wrong address, or wrong port, or there's a firewall in the way...

Comment: Resolved!Firewall was culprit.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possible reasons for this error:

- DNS resolution problems (try `nslookup <hostname>` to verify DNS resolution is working)
- the listener might be running on another port (standard is 1521, check with your DBA if necessary)
- there might be a firewall in between that blocks you from accessing the database (does connecting locally on the server work? Can you connect from another machine?)
- the listener on the database might not be running (try connecting from your machine with `sqlplus`)